# Where is the argument's message displayed?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm learning to write zsh completion scripts and while reading the documentation for `_arguments` I found this part:

> *n:message:action*
>   *n::message:action*
>       This describes the n’th normal argument. The *message* will be
>       printed above the matches generated and the *action* indicates [...]

Where is that *message* printed? I'm trying with the following minimal function but I can't figure it out. Do I need to enable something in my shell?

```bsh
function _test {
  _arguments '-a' '-b[description]:my message:(x y)'
}
```

```
$ compdef _test program
```

This results in:

```
$ program -b <tab>
x y
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in the manual if you know where to look, but the way it's explained, you practically have to know the answer to understand what the manual is saying.

[`_arguments`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005farguments) calls this a “message” and the manual says that this “describes”. So you take a leap of faith — or read the source code of `_arguments` and puzzle out that this message is passed to [`_describe`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fdescribe). The documentation of this function states that

> The `descr` is taken as a string to display above the matches if the `format` style for the `descriptions` tag is set.

A style is something you configure with [`zstyle`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zstyle). The [section “Completion System Configuration”](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-1) documents the format of styles for completion:

> The fields are always in the order `:completion:function:completer:command:argument:tag`.

So you need to call `zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:descriptions' format=SOMETHING`. Or replace the `*` by something else if you only want to do it in certain contexts.

The [documentation of the `descriptions` tag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-descriptions_002c-completion-tag) is not particularly helpful at this stage, but the [documentation of the `format` style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-format_002c-completion-style) is:

> If this is set for the descriptions tag, its value is used as a string to display above matches in completion lists. The sequence `%d` in this string will be replaced with a short description of what these matches are. This string may also contain the output attribute sequences understood by `compadd -X`

See the [`compadd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-compadd) documentation which in turns refers to prompt expansion; you can mainly use [visual effects](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects).

So run

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:descriptions' format '%F{green}%d%f'
```

and you'll see that message in green above the completions. Or

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:program:*:descriptions' format '%F{green}%d%f'
```

if you only want it to apply when completing arguments of `program`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the in-depth answer and documentation references.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `format` zstyle of completion:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
```

Then:

```
$ program -b Tab
Completing my message
x  y
```

See `info zsh format` for details.

That's set by `compinstall` if you follow this menu selection:

```
3.  Styles for changing the way completions are displayed and inserted.
[...]
1.  Change appearance of completion lists:  allows descriptions of
    completions to appear and sorting of different types of completions.
[...]
1.  Print a message above completion lists describing what is being
    completed.
[...]
You can set a string which is displayed on a line above the list of matches
for completions.  A `%d' in this string will be replaced by a brief
description of the type of completion.  For example, if you set the
string to `Completing %d', and type ^D to show a list of files, the line
`Completing files' will appear above that list.  Enter an empty line to
turn this feature off.  If you enter something which doesn't include `%d',
then `%d' will be appended.  Quotation will be added automatically.

description>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I recently switched over to zsh and ran through `compinstall` — technically I should have remembered then about this but I didn't. It's so customizable that it can be a little overwhelming.